# Start new fragment inside viewPager without hiding ac

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity which is a ActionBarActivity with viewPager inside.
Then I have 3 pages.
In the first page there is a tableLayout with tableRow clickListener (inside blocks) from where I would like to start an intent to another layout without hiding TabBar. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a FirstFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            //return FirstFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            switch(position) {
            case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
            case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
            default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        //private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
            createTable(rootView);
            return rootView;
        }

        public static FirstFragment newInstance(String string) {
            FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("msg", "PROVA 1");

            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        void createTable(View rootView){
            TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);


            String categorie[];

            //          MyDatabase db=new MyDatabase(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            //            db.open();  //apriamo il db
            MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            try {

                db.createDataBase();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {

                throw new Error("Unable to create database");

            }

            try {

                db.openDataBase();

            }catch(SQLException sqle){

                throw sqle;

            }



            Cursor c=db.fetchCategorie(); // query


            //startManagingCursor(c);





            //qui vediamo invece come reperire i dati e usarli, in questo caso li stampiamo in una textview

            int categoriaColumn=c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.CategorieMetaData.PRODUCT_CATEGORIA_KEY);  //indici delle colonne
            //int priceCol=c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.ProductsMetaData.PRODUCT_PRICE_KEY);       

            ArrayList<String> categorieList = new ArrayList<String>();

            if(c.moveToFirst()){  //se va alla prima entry, il cursore non è vuoto
                do {


                    categorieList.add(c.getString(categoriaColumn)); //add to arraylist

                    //productsTv.append("Product Name:"+c.getString(nameCol)+", Price:"+c.getInt(priceCol)+"\n"); //estrazione dei dati dalla entry del cursor
                    //Log.d("Prova", "PROVA:"+ "Product Name:"+c.getString(categoriaColumn)+", Price:"+c.getInt(priceCol)+"\n");
                } while (c.moveToNext());//iteriamo al prossimo elemento
            }




            db.close();

            categorie = categorieList.toArray(new String[categorieList.size()]);


            for (int i = 0; i < categorie.length; i++) {
                TableRow tbRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                tbRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
                tbRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
                tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv1.setId(i);

                tv1.setText(categorie[i]);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                tbRow.addView(imageView);
                tbRow.addView(tv1);

                ll.addView(tbRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                final String finalCategorie[] = categorie;
                final int finalI = i;
                final View finalRootView = rootView;

                tbRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        //             Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, detailActivity.class);
                        //             newIntent.putExtra("key", strings[finalI]);
                        Log.d("TEST", "Row selected: " + finalCategorie[finalI]);
                        //             startActivity(newIntent);

                        //     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EventiFragment.class);
                        //     startActivity(intent);



                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }



    public static class SecondFragment extends Fragment  {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.FragmentSecond);
            tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

            return v;
        }

        public static SecondFragment newInstance(String string) {

            SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("msg", "Prova 2");

            f.setArguments(b);

            return f;
        }
    }

    public static class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_fragment, container, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.FragmentThird);      
            tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

            return v;
        }

        public static ThirdFragment newInstance(String text) {

            ThirdFragment f = new ThirdFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("msg", "Prova 3");

            f.setArguments(b);

            return f;
        }
    }

    public static class EventiFragment extends Fragment  {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventi_fragment, container, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.FragmentEventi);
            tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

            return v;
        }

        public static EventiFragment newInstance(String string) {

            EventiFragment f = new EventiFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("msg", "Prova 2");

            f.setArguments(b);

            return f;
        }
    }
}
```

first_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.alain.ama.caccamo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/main_photo_description"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/main_photo" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

eventi_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.alain.ama.caccamo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FragmentEventi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="26sp"/>
```

Comment: I'd really like to help you. Unfortunately you need to include more information on what you're doing and less code. Every bit of code should actually pertain directly to the problem, if at all possible.

Comment: Thank's for the help. So: I'm showing a list of categories in a tableLayout and onClick inside tableRow I need to "start an intent" without hiding the tabBar. If I use the Intent the layout starts as a new activity.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't believe that this is possible, however what you could do is hide part of the layout, and whenever you were to start the intent, just make the hidden part visible.

Comment: thanks'. good idea. I was just thinking about how to get back to the previous layout when (for example) user touches back button.

Comment: When the user touches the back button. Hide the layout. So I'll post an answer with the solution i have. Just give me an hour or two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would create a separate layout, but instead of putting the layout in two separate XML files, put it all in one. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/intent_replacement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
    <!-- Here's the stuff for the supposed intent -->

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So in this you can have one attribute called `visible` then programmatically you just get the Layout as an object and when an item in the table is clicked on use `intentLayoutObject.setVisibility(true)`

Likewise when you get back button pressed `intentLayoutObject.setVisibility(false)`